# Calculating totals from two different hashes

Tags: ruby, hash, lookup

I have two hashes:

For example, one contains a list of dishes and their prices

```
dishes = {"Chicken"=>12.5, "Pizza"=>10, "Pasta"=>8.99}
```

The other is a basket hash i.e. I've selected one pasta and two pizzas:

```
basket = {"Pasta"=>1, "Pizza"=>2}
```

Now I am trying to calculate the total cost of the basket but can't seem to get my references right.

Have tried

```
basket.inject { |item, q| dishes[item] * q }
```

But keep getting the following error

> NoMethodError: undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass

Comment: This is not related to your problem, but important nonetheless: never, ever, *ever*, **EVER** use `Float`s for money. `Float`s are inaccurate *by definition*, and "inaccurate" and "money" *really* don't mix well. (Just look at the result value in [@Ursus' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43027417/2988).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> basket.inject { |item, q| dishes[item] * q }
> ```

Let's look at the documentation for [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) to see what is going on. `inject` "folds" the collection into a single object, by taking a "starting object" and then repeatedly applying the binary operation to the starting object and the first element, then to the result of that and the second element, then to the result of *that* and the third element, and so forth.

So, the block receives two arguments: the current value of the accumulator and the current element, and the block returns the new value of the accumulator for the next invocation of the block. If you don't supply a starting value for the accumulator, then the first element of the collection is used.

So, during the first iteration here, since you didn't supply a starting value for the accumulator, the value is going to be the first element; and iteration is going to start from the second element. This means that during the first iteration, `item` is going to be `['Pasta', 1]` and `q` is going to be `['Pizza', 2]`. Let's just run through the example in our heads:

```
dishes[item] * q                    # item is ['Pasta', 1]
dishes[['Pasta', 1]] * q            # q is ['Pizza', 2]
dishes[['Pasta', 1]] * ['Pizza', 2] # there is no key ['Pasta', 1] in dishes
nil * ['Pizza', 2]                  # nil doesn't have * method
```

Ergo, you get a `NoMethodError`.

Now, I believe, what you *actually* wanted to do was something like this:

```
basket.inject(0.0) {|sum, (item, q)| sum + dishes[item] * q }
#             ↑↑↑    ↑↑↑             ↑↑↑↑↑
```

- You don't want to accumulate orders, you want to accumulate numbers, so you need to supply a number as the starting value; if you don't, the starting value will be the first element, which is an order, not a number
- You were mixing up the meaning of the block parameters
- You weren't actually *summing* anything

Now, while `inject` is capable of summing (in fact, `inject` is capable of *anything*, it is a *general* iteration operation, i.e. anything you could do with a loop, you can also do with `inject`), it is usually better to use more specialized operations if they exist. In this case, a more specialized operation for summing *does* exist, and it is called [`Enumerable#sum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum):

```
basket.sum {|item, q| dishes[item] * q }
```

But there is a deeper underlying problem with your code: Ruby is an object-oriented language. It is not an array-of-hash-of-strings-and-floats-oriented language. You should build objects that represent your domain abstractions:

```
class Dish < Struct.new(:name, :price)
  def to_s; "#{name}: $#{price}" end
  def *(num) num * price end
  def coerce(other) [other, price] end
end

require 'bigdecimal'
require 'bigdecimal/util'

dishes = {
  chicken: Dish.new('Chicken', '12.5'.to_d), 
  pizza: Dish.new('Pizza', '10'.to_d),
  pasta: Dish.new('Pasta', '8.99'.to_d)
}

class Order < Struct.new(:dish, :quantity)
  def to_s; "#{quantity} * #{dish}" end
  def total; quantity * dish end
end

class Basket
  def initialize(*orders)
    self.orders = orders
  end

  def <<(order)
    orders << order
  end

  def to_s; orders.join("\n") end

  def total; orders.sum(&:total) end

  private

  attr_accessor :orders
end

basket = Basket.new(
  Order.new(dishes[:pasta], 1), 
  Order.new(dishes[:pizza], 2)
)

basket.total
#=> 0.2899e2
```

Now, of course, for such a simple example, this is overkill. But I hope that you can see that despite this being more code, it is also much much simpler. There is no complex navigation of complex nested structures, because a) there are no complex nested structures and b) all the objects know how to take care of themselves, there is never a need to "take apart" an object to examine its parts and run complex calculations on them, because the objects themselves know their own parts and how to run calculations on them.

Note: personally, I do *not* think that allowing arithmetic operations on `Dish`es is a good idea. It is more of a "neat hack" that I wanted to show off in this code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

With Ruby 2.4, you could use [`Hash(Enumerable)#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) with a block :

```
basket = {"Pasta"=>1, "Pizza"=>2}
prices = {"Chicken"=>12.5, "Pizza"=>10, "Pasta"=>8.99}

basket.sum{ |dish, quantity| quantity * prices[dish] }
# 28.99
```

## Data structure

#### dishes

`dishes` (what I called `prices` to avoid writing `dishes[dish]`) is the correct data structure :

- Hash lookup is fast
- If you want to update the price of a dish, you only have to do it in one place
- It's basically a mini database.

#### basket

`basket` is also fine as a Hash, but only if you don't oder any dish more than once. If you want to order 2 pizzas, 1 pasta and then 3 pizzas again :

```
{"Pizza"=>2, "Pasta" => 1, "Pizza" =>3}
=> {"Pizza"=>3, "Pasta"=>1}
```

you'll lose the first order.

In that case, you might want to use an array of pairs (a 2-element array with `dish` and `quantity`) :

```
basket = [["Pizza", 2], ["Pasta", 1], ["Pizza", 3]]
```

With this structure, you could use the exact same syntax to get the total as with a Hash :

```
basket.sum{ |dish, quantity| quantity * prices[dish] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
basket.inject(0) do |acc, item|
  dish, q = item
  acc + (dishes[dish] * q)
end
 => 28.990000000000002
```

one line

```
basket.inject(0) { |acc, item| acc + (dishes[item.first] * item.last) }
```

Your variables for the block are wrong. You have the accumulator and an item (that it's an hash)

Comment: would it be better to use an array for the "basket" instead?

Comment: What about just an array of hashes that for every item (that it's an hash) has a cost and a quantity?

Comment: You mean `basket = [{"Pasta"=>1}, {"Pizza"=>2}]` then do something similar to how I approached it before?

Comment: `[{ name: "pasta", cost: 10, quantity: 1 }, { name: "pizza", cost: 5, quantity: 2 }]`

Comment: Or just an hash. `{ "pasta": { cost: 10, quantity: 1 }, "pizza": { cost: 5, quantity: 2 } }`

Answer (score 0):

```
2.2.0 :011 > basket.inject(0){ |sum, (item, q)| sum + dishes[item].to_f * q }
=> 28.990000000000002
```

Comment: It's basically Ursus's answer with a slightly nicer syntax. This should be a comment IMHO.

Comment: Agreed, there is a minor difference though, it guards against the missing price. But that may not be the desired outcome. If an exception should be raised when the price is missing, dishes[item] should be used instead of dishes[item].to_f